# Appending columns from a table to my active table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, database

I am trying to append three columns from srs2016 to srs2013_1 using this sql.

```
INSERT INTO srs2013_1 (the_geom, agency_responsible, description)
    SELECT             the_geom, agency_responsible, description
    FROM srs2016
```

The statement fail with this message:

> Syntax error: column "agency_responsible" of relation "srs2013_1" does
> not exist

I have tried adding quotes.  Did not solve it.

Comment: How are the records in each table related - do they have an ID or other value they can be linked on? The SQL you're trying to use will depend on that...

Comment: are you trying to have three new columns in srs2013_1 with the contents of srs2016 or you are trying to add all the contents of 2016 into the 2013 table that has the same schema? your question needs a better explanation of the schema of both tables and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT INTO` will add values from one table to another (not columns). Your query looks OK. Are you sure is not a typo? `agency_responsible` is well written? A workaround if the problem continues is using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM srs2013_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM srs2016
```

I use `*` because I understand all columns are the same and they are ordered in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Your question says 'append columns' while your code is really about appending rows, or unioning, two tables. There's already an answer for how you would union; here's how you would append the fields to your new table.

```
alter table srs2013_1 add column the_geom geometry(Geometry,SRID); -- where SRID is your coordinate system
alter table srs2013_1 add column agency_responsible text;
alter table srs2013_1 add column description text;
```

You now have 3 new empty fields in your table. To update them with values from your other table, you'd need a field with common values. Assuming that field is called `featname`:

update srs2013_1 a set the_geom = b.the_geom from srs2016 b where a.featname = b.featname